# Why my "Repeated Strings" code isn't working? || Hackerrank || JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
((s, n) => {
    let nStrings = ''; // stores the string we get after multiplying s to reach length n.
    let aNos = 0; // stores the number of 'a's present in nStrings;

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
            if (nStrings.length === n) {
                break;
            } else {
                  nStrings += s[j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (let k = 0; k < nStrings.length; k++) {
        if (nStrings[k] === 'a') {
            aNos++;
        }
    }

    return aNos;
})('a', 1000000000000);
```

Above is my code written for the problem "Repeated Strings" in Hackerrank ([Problem link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup)). I wrote this in JavaScript. When I ran this code it shows that it ran out of memory. I don't understand why.

Please review my code and let me know why it failed.
Thank you.

Comment: There’s an entire site about reviewing code. Do you have a specific problem with this code?

Comment: It might have something to do with trying to create a string that is 1 trillion characters long. Not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the the count of `a` in the given string, divide the length by the string length, get the integer part and multiply with the count of the given string.

The second part is to get the rest of the wanted length with remainder operator and iterate the given string for getting a count of `a`.

Return the sum of the integer and rest count.

```js
function getCount(string, length) {
    var first = 0,
        count = 0,
        rest = 0,
        restCount = 0,
        i;
        
    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) if (string[i] === 'a') count++;
        
    first = Math.floor(length / string.length) * count;
    rest = length % string.length;
    
    for (i = 0; i < rest; i++) if (string[i] === 'a') restCount++;
    
    return first + restCount;
}

console.log(getCount('aba', 10)); // 7
```